# Is -1 less than 0.1?

Tags: number-theory, logic

In a High School Maths Test, I presumed that since -1 has as much mathematical mass as a whole unit [-1 x -1 = 1, 1 x 1 = 1] and 0.1 represents one tenth of a unit, that -1 is greater than 0.1

-1 is to the left of 0.1 on a number line but does that make it lesser than 0.1?

Clearly, the teacher believed I was wrong but inexplicably so and no marking comments to help me.  Can someone please help me to explain the difference?

Comment: Answering your second line: yes.  Thinking of mass is a useful analogy for **positive** numbers, but negative mass doesn't really make sense.  So when negatives are involved, the better way to think of it is that "further left on the number line" means "less".

Answer (score 5):

If it is $-1^\circ C$ outside, it is colder (and not warmer)  than with $0.1^\circ C$. If your bank balance shows $-1\$$ you are poorer (and not richer) than with $0.1\$$. Best you think of the number line with negatives to the left, positives to the right. Then "less than" is the same as "to the left of".

Answer (score 2):

If we add $1$ to both, we obtain $-1+1=0$ and $0.1+1=1.1$ and it's clear that $0<1.1$.  (We can picture this as "shifting" the number line by $1$.)

What you seem to be getting confused with is that $-1$ is greater in [magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28mathematics%29) than $0.1$.  It's true that $|-1|>|0.1|$.

Answer (score 2):

"Greater than" isn't really about size, or, as you put it, "mathematical mass". It's about position on the number line. The number line extends towards $-\infty$ on the left and towards $\infty$ on the right, and $a>b$ if and only if $a$ is strictly to the right of $b$ on the number line.

The idea that you have of measuring the size of a number so that $-1$ is "bigger" than $0.1$ is exactly what the absolute value function does. The number $|a|$ is the distance between $a$ and $0$, which is a good way to think about its, I don't know, "length". So then $|-1|>|0.1|$. But the question on your exam wasn't about absolute values, so unfortunately your teacher is right this time around.

Comment: This is a good answer. +1 for you. The OP is clearly recognizing a difference in magnitude, but is confused by terminology. Although by no means universally used, the terms "bigger" and "smaller" are often used to compare magnitudes of numbers (as opposed to "greater" and "lesser", which strictly are concerned with order of the numbers on the line). "Bigger" and "smaller" can be used in normed spaces where there is no notion of order (for example, in $\mathbb{C}$).